KafkaProducer per task or Singleton KafkaProducer
I have several tasks that are running in parallel(ExecutorService and Runnable tasks). Is it a good option to use one KafkaProducer instance (Spring singleton bean) for all of them? In this case, how will the sending queue be built if two tasks simultaneously call the send() method? Now I’m creating a producer per runnable. I am ooking for ways to optimize.

KafkaProducer is designed to be thread-safe, so calling its send method simultaneously in multiple threads should be more than ok.
As far as I know, Kafka optimizes concurrency by buffering the sent records for each partition internally and batching together the records. Here is a nice article about Kafka Producer design.
All of the above and much more are configurable.
